# Using InternetSetOption() to set both 32bit and 64bit browser proxy settings

Tags: c#, winapi, webbrowser-control, wininet, internetsetoption

I am using the class provided [here](https://github.com/chentiangemalc/ProxyUtils/tree/master/SetProxy) to programmatically set the Internet Explorer proxy settings via InternetSetOption() from wininet.dll.

However, if my project is set to target the x86 platform it will only change the proxy settings for the 32-bit version of IE, and if i set it to 'Any CPU' it will only change the settings for the 64-bit version of IE.

How can I use this class (or indeed InternetSetOption) to target both versions of Internet Explorer. It must be possible as FiddlerCore does the same thing with ease.

Comment: Use two executables, one for each bitness

Comment: Is that really the only way? The environment i want to roll this out to has a mixture of machines and I'd rather have one file fixes all.

Comment: Ok, if you want to do it that way, go for it.

Comment: But this sounds like the wrong way to go about it. It's a sysadmin task not a programming task. Use group policy or however you roll out settings on your network. Talk to the sysadmin.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem - using the sample SetProxy tool from the link you provided, build for x86, change any of the proxy settings and they are reflected in both IE 32-bit and 64-bit. This is a fresh Win7 SP1 build with IE8.